# Synchronized block and while loop optimal ordering

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, synchronized

If I am waiting on a condition like so (note: `current` is an `AtomicInteger` and `target` is an `int`):

```
while (current.get() < target) {
    try {
        synchronized (current) {
            current.wait();
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
}
```

then should the synchronized go inside the while (as above) or outside, like so?

```
synchronized (current) {
    while (current.get() < target) {
        try {
            current.wait();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
    }
}
```

My question is, what is the practical / functional difference between the above two pieces of code and when should one be used over the other?

EDIT: The loop is exited when another thread performs the following operation

```
if (current.incrementAndGet() >= target) {
    synchronized (current) {
        current.notify();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which thread is incrementing/decrementing `current` (don't see that in the code, but the loop has to be exited...)? If it's another thread, you might want to check the effect of `synchronized (current)` on calls to `current.increment/decrementAndGet` made on other threads.

Comment: @ernest_k I have updated the question to show the exit condition.

Answer (score 0):

It is decided by what is the [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) of code is, rather than by a best practice.

---

However, it is best to keep the critical section code length to the minimum since you allow only one thread to enter it at a time. Otherwise, to stretch to an extreme, you can synchronize your entire program and make it safe.

Comment: @SinaMadani: ...If that option is otherwise correct.

Comment: Although it reduces the size of the "critical section" I do wonder whether there is any overhead of re-acquiring the lock every time the loop is executed? Either way theoretically the condition is only evaluated twice at most so I suppose it doesn't matter?

Comment: @SinaMadani: The code complexity will be O(n) whether you acquire the lock inside the loop or outside. There may be overhead but it doesn’t change the Big-O. To be sure, profile your code and measure the time.